# PHP How to decode plain text with "=E9" "=E9" string

Tags: php, encoding, imap, charset

Probably an encoding ssue with some charset (windows-1252/windows-1258)

Hi everybody,

I actually work on an IMAP reader from PHP. I have no issue on the IMAP system itself, all work but some mails I try to read have issue :
On Plain text, with Windows charset (Windows-1252/windows-1258), Sometimes I have some special char encoded like this : "=92" ("'"), "=E9" ("é"), "=E0" ("à")

Anybody know how can I detect this charset and how to have an easy function to translate string (I understand I can do that with str_replace but in this case I will need the full list of char to be replaced and it's probably very long...) ?

My script is in UTF-8 if it's important to understand the issue

Have a nice day

Comment: not totaly, some chars on my exemple are still in error : =E0 // =92 // =9C, I suppose windows charset didn't use a good mode and break the UTF8 convertion

Comment: Can you share a sample email that without personal information? or the code you are using

Comment: I use the javanile php-imap2 library and this function :

`$recupere_text=imap2_fetchbody($imap_connection, $imap_mail_num, $imap_part_number, FT_PEEK);` 

Example of mail content this function return (without any encoding at this moment) :
`Ok, vous pourrez m=92envoyer votre =E9bauche de structure, poste =
occup=E9 et une
activit=E9  pour que je jette un =9Cil et vous dise si vous etes sur le =
bon
chemin ?`

Comment: The duplicate question/answer works, see [the example here](https://tio.run/##XVA9a8MwEN31K44QcALOUEOhxjEZ0ha6NENbMhpbvmI1jqRIJ0Na@tvdk72ECg2nex@nd7az47jd2c4K8Rm0JGU0tChNi9XFOqVptfTk1vAjgE@soYRLMIRtNeF102M1K2ZqcctU0uhhlRxfXh8Px7fNXXafJSkkH@/PmwcubgQOKTg9dQrxK8SyMe2VHRaHUwqDCR6sCc7hN5zLPEM9mCs6BsghlE95UwfZIX8d2CBI9sKUFZ4YBSNlsEwCJAgaoeacg6LYmVw5EMJXvMT8oKHM96qP7GlwqzzbqvmBhB48a/ro3PC6eO5ZadgtCiFQdub//mKQdTGOfw), if you replace 'ISO-8859-2' by 'WINDOWS-1252'.

Comment: Thanks @kiko-software, I stupidely not try to change charset on the example... That works perfecly now !